# What happened between episodes 7 and 8 of Konosuba

Tags: konosuba

At the beginning of episode 8 we see [Wiz](http://myanimelist.net/character/123868/Wiz) for the first time but Aqua and Kazuma already know who she is. They have a short flashback to how they meet, but it doesn't go into very much detail.

So I was wondering what happened between episode 7 and 8. Why did they agree to take over her task of sending the lost souls to heaven?

Also was there anything else from the source material that was skipped in the anime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the manga, it wasn't her quest. Wiz took pity in the souls of the people who hadn't enough money to pay the priest to cleanse the souls of their friends and relatives. These souls would wander around. So she cleansed them for free.

Kazuma and the rest just took the quest to cleanse the cemetry, because the party thought, it would be the ideal job for Aqua to level up. After defeating some undead, they notice Wiz and want to fight her. But then they hear her story.[image: Party starts the quest][image: They meet the lich][image: Wiz describes her actions]

Comment: wow. i really think this is important but why does the anime version skipped this part? or haven't elaborate this side story? Also i wonder a bit why the people in that city love Wiz so much. Maybe your answer is the reason for it too.

Comment: @nameme I don't know, why the anime skipped it. But it is the reason the people love her. She's helping them for free...